# How to convert PDFObject/PDFDictionary to to PDFArray

Tags: itext

I am trying to parse the tag structure of a tagged PDF using iTextSharp library.
When a tag contains more than one children tags we can access those children using the following code:

```
PdfDictionary docElement = kids.GetAsDict(0);                
PdfArray kids_doc = docElement.GetAsArray(PdfName.K);
```

But when a tag contains only one child I am unable to use above code as it returns null instead of an PDFArray object.
So I tried to typecast PDFObject to PDFArray with following code:

```
var docElement = kids.GetAsDict(0);
PdfObject pdfObj = docElement.Get(PdfName.K);                    
PdfArray arr = (PdfArray)pdfObj;
```

but it throws exception as unable to convert PDFIndirectReference to PDFArray.
Can anyone help me to get the output as : kids of a Tag if it is >=1 in PDFArray object

Comment: A dictionary and an array in PDF are two different objects. A dictionary is a set of keys and values; an array is as series of values. If you are confronted with a dictionary in PDF, you should treat it as a dictionary. You should not try to convert it into an array, because that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks Bruno for your suggestion. But is there a way we can typecast the PDFObject to PDFArray without getting the exception I have mentioned in the last paragraph. like here :                                                              
    PdfArray arr = (PdfArray)pdfObj;

Comment: You know the answer to that question yourself. If you do `PdfArray kids_doc = docElement.GetAsArray(PdfName.K);` and the value corresponding with `PdfName.K` is not an array, no exception is thrown, but `kids_doc` will be `null`. Obviously, if you cast an object that is not a `PdfArray` to a `PdfArray` object, you will (and should) get an exception. In short: don't cast an object that is not a `PdfArray` to a `PdfArray` object.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Bruno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue I was facing with a different approach : instead of converting PDFObject/PDFDictionary to PDFArray, I created new PDFArray object and then removed the existing key for PDFName.K and added the previously created array as PDFName.K. I am giving the solution as below:

```
PdfArray arr = new PdfArray();
PdfObject pdfObj = docElement.Get(PdfName.K);  
arr.Add(pdfObj);                                        
for (int i = 1; i < kidsCount; i++)
{                        
    arr.Add(kids[i]);
}
docElement.Remove(PdfName.K);
docElement.Put(PdfName.K,arr);
```